# Need to create/delete text file in Unix box from windows

Tags: shell, unix, ftp, sftp, informatica

I have a requirement where i need to create and delete a text file on unix from my windows server where i have informatica installed.
Using workflow i was able to place file in unix but not able to find a way to delete already existing file.
Also the client does not want us to download any additional software like putty on windows server.

Please feel free to ask for more information if required.

Comment: Your (s)ftp client will have "delete" and/or "rm" commands. Check the documentation for it.

Answer (score 0):

if you are able to drop .sh (shell script) and execut it on unix then you can do that with "**rmdir yourfolder**" command, if you folder has andything under then you will need to use "**rm -r yourfolder**", if files inside the folder have any dependicies you need to use "**rm -rf yourfolder**". 
Just make sure that you will navigate to the correct folder where you are deleting things.

Br, Aljaž.

Comment: Sorry just use rm yourfile.txt and it should do the job. If you wnat to create it do echo >> mycreatedfile.txt

Comment: Thank you for the response.
rm commands works for me using putty, but how can i run a shell script from windows machine?

Comment: Hi you have CMd script or SH (shell script), but in any case you will not be able to execute windows script from windows machine to your linux machine or what you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Command Task` in Informatica Workflow to invoke syntax mentioned by @Aljaz

Comment: Check that the powercenter user has pe

Comment: Check that the powercenter user has the necessary permissions on the affected file